# When $Rx = Re$ and $e^2 =e$

Tags: commutative-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with identity. Suppose $x , e \in R$ with $Rx = Re \mbox{ and } e^2 = e$. What is the best thing that we can say about $x$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can say that $x^2$ divides $x$, i.e. that $x$ is [Von Neumann regular](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_regular_ring).

Comment: Yes. Since $x$ is invertible in $Re$ (which is a ring with unit $e$), say $xy=e$, then $u = ey + (1-e)$ is invertible in $R$ with $x=ue$.